# QTreeView control left click vs right click

Tags: python, pyside

In my QTreeView when a user clicks an item in the list, i popup a dialog beneath the clicked treeview item. However, I only want this to happen when the user Left clicks. Currently this popup is displayed when the user both right-clicks and left clicks.

I want the context menu to show, like it does now, when the user right-clicks. And the popup dialog to show when only when the user left clicks an item. The right-click should still act as normal, selecting and item.

How do i fix this? The error occurs when i right-click over the furthest right column.

[image]

```
import os, sys, pprint
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800, 400)

        self.uiSearch = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.uiItems = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.uiItems.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiItems.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.uiItems.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.uiItems.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())
        self.uiItems.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiSearch)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiItems)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        for i in range(10):
            col1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item' + str(i))
            col2 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item' + str(i))
            col3 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item' + str(i))
            self.uiItems.model().appendRow([col1,col2,col3])

        self.uiItems.clicked.connect(self.clickedItem)
        self.uiItems.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openContextMenu)

        self.myMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu('Menu', self)
        self.myMenu.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Test',self))


    def clickedItem(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            rect = self.uiItems.visualRect(index)
            pos = self.uiItems.viewport().mapToGlobal(rect.bottomLeft())
            # create editor
            dlg = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)
            dlg.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
            dlg.resize(rect.width(), 100)
            dlg.move(pos)
            dlg.show()


    def openContextMenu(self):
        self.myMenu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better. When I test your code and I click left, the QDialog opens, whereas when I right click, the QMenu opens. What is the problem? I can not reproduce the behavior you show in the image.

Comment: try to right-click over the last column, you'll see both appear

Comment: No, only the QMenu opens, it is probably a bug of an old version. I have tested it with PyQt5-5.11.3/PySide2-5.12 and it works correctly.

Comment: hmmm yeah this exists in the PySide that im using...

Comment: I recommend you to establish which backend you are using and the version. PyQt and PySide are libraries that often have a different behavior, in addition the same problem happens with PyQt4 and PyQt5 / PySide and PySide2 since they are bindings of Qt4 and Qt5 respectively.

Comment: I just tested it on PySide 1.2.4 on Linux and it works correctly, I recommend trying it on another pc and try to use the latest version of the libraries. For me it is not reproducible

Comment: yeah I'm doing it with PySide and when i right-click the last column, both the popup and the context menu appear. And I only want one or the other based on which mouse click triggered the event.